# d3 text label format based on value

Tags: javascript, text, d3.js, label

I have this chart that I need to make some a label bold based on a variable. However I am not sure how in D3 to achieve this. I think may need to use the .each function. The line .style("font-weight", "bold") makes all the text labels bold but I only want certain values to be made bold. Any ideas on the correct syntax for this?

```
    g.append("svg:text")
        .each(function(d) { d.angle = (d.startAngle + d.endAngle) / 2; })
        .attr("dy", ".35em")
        .style("font-family", "helvetica, arial, sans-serif")
        .style("font-size", "10px")
        //.style("font-weight", "bold")
        .attr("text-anchor", function(d) { return d.angle > Math.PI ? "end" : null; })
        .attr("transform", function(d) {
          return "rotate(" + (d.angle * 180 / Math.PI - 90) + ")"
              + "translate(" + (r0 + 36) + ")"
              + (d.angle > Math.PI ? "rotate(180)" : "");
        })
        .text(function(d) { return rdr(d).gname; });
```

Comment: Could you create a function for the font-weight attribute or style that returns bold when a condition is true?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This approach seems to work...

```
        .style("font-weight", function(d) {if(selectedvaluessplit.indexOf( rdr(d).gname ) > -1) {return "bold"}})
```

this is the answer